# How to get the number of combinations from some number that contains only two different digits?

Tags: delphi, numbers, combinations

For example, two-digit number have 4 combinations: 11, 12, 21, 22. Three-digit number have 8 combinations: 111, 112,...222.

- How to get number of combinations for number that have 4, 5, ... 10 or more digits?

Thanks

P.S. This refers to the Delphi :)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The answer is 2<sup>*N*</sup>, where *N* is the number of digits.

This is a purely mathematical problem, and concerns very basic combinatorics. It is easy to see why 2<sup>*N*</sup> is the right answer. Indeed, there are two ways to choose the first digit. *For each such choice*, there are two ways to chose the second digit. Hence, there are 2×2 ways to chose a two-digit number. *For each* such number, there are two ways to add a third digit, making 2×2×2 ways to construct a three-digit number. Hence, there are

```
2 × 2 × ... × 2 = 2^N
```

ways to construct a *N*-digit number.

In Delphi, you compute 2<sup>*N*</sup> by `Power(2, N)` (`uses Math`). [A less naïve way, which works for *N* < 31, is `1 shl N`.]

Comment: Thanks for the well explained answer. My area of math is geometry, combinatorics has always been my bad side.